# SQL ORDER String (NumberOrder/Year)

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have this String saved as VARCHAR to a MySQL database LIKE This (NumberOrder/CurrentYear) 
Example: 1/2014, 2/2014, 15/2014, 635/2014, 1/2013, 5/2013....etc

While retrieving data into a table I want to Sort Data by Order like this:
1/2013, 5/2013, 1/2014, 2/2014, 15/2014, 635/2014 ...etc

I tried this QUERY :

```
SELECT * FROM `tableX` ORDER BY n_inscription ASC
```

But it doesn't work...

N.B: I have also Strings like this : 01/2014, 06/2013, 02/2014, 05/2014...etc

Comment: This is because you're attempting to sort based on two parts of the same column, in the opposite direction.  You won't be able to use an index (as-is) to fulfill queries based on this, so doing this will be slow.  It'd be better to split this into separate columns, store it, and sort based on that.  You're storing derived information, or a multi-part key, in one column, which is usually something you're not supposed to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `tableX` 
ORDER BY right(n_inscription, 4) * 1,
         substring_index(n_inscription, '/', 1) * 1
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04c85/1)

Comment: hmmm! the example you gave me in sqlfiddle is working. maybe i did something wrong! i'm gonna try again.. thanks anyway.. :)